# Set Coordinates Reference Systems to a list of SpatialPolygon

Tags: transformation, spatial, coordinate-systems

I want to set the Coordinates Reference Systems to a list of SpatialPolygon called `SpP`

```
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
```

I want to give a coordinate reference system to each features in the list. `CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"`

Comment: Not so much at the end.

Comment: What do you mean?  An example data is always useful for people who try it.

Comment: I meant for the link u sent me earlier. I could not find information on setting CRS for a SpatialPolygon list

Answer (score 1):

For any `Spatial*` object, you can set the CRS with the `proj4string` function.

For your example:

```
proj4string(SpP) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

See `?proj4string` and `?CRS` for more details.